# Can a Gentile be an eved Hashem?

Tags: gentiles, slave-serve-eved-avadim

Shalom.

Some discussion of the concept of an eved Hashem can be found here:

https://www.shortvort.com/2618/

And here:

https://www.kby.org/english/torat-yavneh/view.asp?id=3684

My question is: Can a Gentile become an eved Hashem without undergoing gerus?

This question was prompted by the following considerations:

(1) Israel is described in multiple places as HKBH’s servants. Might these verses imply automatically that Gentiles are not?

(2) I am not aware of Gentiles being subject to the laws regarding the piercing of the ear, which would imply that they are not servants in the same sense as Israel (see second article).

(3) Restrictions on Gentile Torah study would seem to preclude the ‘revising 101 times’ that is said to be the mark of an eved in the second article.

(4) On the other hand, Gentiles are free to take on optional mitzvot (Rambam), which would enable them to fulfil one of the conditions of an eved cited in the second article (going ‘beyond the letter’). And clearly there are Gentiles who are free, and thus not encumbered with the status of being a ‘servant of a servant’ (which, according to the second article, disqualifies someone from being an eved Hashem).

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Job was called “my servant” by G-d himself, although some say he wasn’t a Jew

Comment: @שלום - that’s great, thanks - I hadn’t thought of that. My blessings to you :)

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii - shalom Rabbi - have edited to include the points that prompted the question. :)

Comment: @שלום Also nevuchadnezar https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%9B%D7%96_%D7%95 See page 122 https://hakirah.org/Vol%203%20Broyde.pdf

Comment: @Double AA - might nevuchadnezar have been called an eved Hashem merely ironically, in order to shame His servants? I.e. In the same way as a man might call a wasp his ‘friend’ who stings his enemy etc. etc. ?

Comment: See last Rambam in Hil. Shemitah VeYovel, כל איש ואיש מכל באי עולם אשר נדבה רוחו...לעמוד לפני ה' לשרתו *ולעבדו*...הרי זה נתקדש קדש קדשים